# Transpose Data in an excel sheet to unique values

Tags: excel, database

I have an excel sheet which contains monthly values as so

[image: excel original]

I want to transpose this sheet into the below format for each value uniquely. As example I am doing so for the first one

[image: formatted excel]

I want to know that for each month given in row headers from January to December , how can I automate this process to generated the above excel. If any one can help?

Comment: To 'automate' that will of course require someone to design and write code. Be that excel functions and/or vba. And, as SO isn't a free coding service that someone is you, with support here to address specific issues/bugs. However, what you've posted amounts to simply asking "can someone do some work for  me for free?". See also [help – on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1st table is in Sheet1, put this is D2 cell of table 2 and drag downwards..

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A:$C,0,MATCH($C2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)-1),MATCH($B2,Sheet1!$B:$B),MATCH(D$1,Sheet1!$D$2:$F$2,0))
```

Idea :

use https://exceljet.net/index-and-match to 'load' value from Sheet1. Offset() with match() is used to 'shift' the reference/source cell/data selection.

Please share if it works/understandable/not. ( :